# T4MVC 2.6.44 missing T4MVC.settings.t4 file

Tags: t4mvc

I downloaded the latest version of T4MVC 2.6.44 from http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/releases/view/41582. When I unzipped the file, it has T4MVC.tt and T4MVC.cs. And I don't see T4MVC.settings.t4. I double checked that the T4MVCVB version has T4MVCVB.settings.t4. I am getting an error saying that T4MVC.settings.t4 is missing while trying to use T4MVC it in my solution.

Any help on this matter is appreciated.

Update: I found the T4MVC.settings.t4 file at: http://code.google.com/p/funnelweb/source/browse/src/FunnelWeb.Web/T4MVC.settings.t4?r=b2af322275f6bc281ced2dfb533c20fff92edabc&spec=svnb2af322275f6bc281ced2dfb533c20fff92edabc

Does it mean it is not included as part of T4MVC download?

Thanks,
eyob

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my bad, I just didn't package it correctly last time around. I just fixes it. A couple notes:

- Most people now get T4MVC via NuGet
- The settings file is now named T4MVC.tt.settings.t4 (not the extra .tt in there)